Proving that a quotient space is not Hausdorff
a number of examples were given already, like this one : Show that the quotient space is not Hausdorf but I can't quite conclude on the following:
Let ~ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ by : x ~ y if x = y = 0 or if xy > 0

How many elemnts does $\mathbb{R}$ / ~ contain ?
Describe the open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ / ~
Deduce that $\mathbb{R}$ / ~ is not Hausdorff

Here are my attempts :

3 elements, since :
[x] = {0} for x = 0,
[x] = ]-$\infty$,0[ for x < 0, and
[x] = ]0, $\infty$[ for x > 0.

As we know, a set V in $\mathbb{R}$ / ~ is open iff $\pi^{-1}$(V) is an open set in R.


$\pi^{-1}$({0}) = {0} which is not open, so {0} is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ / ~
Any open set in the other two equivalence classes is open since its pre-image by $\pi$ is an open set.

I foresee that proving the quotient space isn't Hausdorff has something to do with what happens around {0} but I can't quite put my finger on it.


I agree with your attempt for $1$.
As you mention in $2$, a set $V\subset \mathbb{R}/\sim$ is open iff $\pi^{-1}(V)$ is an open set. Notice that if $[0]\in V$ then $0\in \pi^{-1}(V)$. If this set is open, then it must contain negative and positive elements, so $[-1],[1]\in V$ and thus $V=\mathbb{R}/\sim$. It is easy to see that $\{[-1]\},\{[1]\}$ and $\{[-1],[1]\}$ are open too. Thus, all the open sets in $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ are $$\emptyset, \{[-1]\},\{[1]\},\{[-1],[1]\}, \mathbb{R}/\sim$$
As for $3$, the above argument proves that every open set that contains $[0]$ must contain $[-1]$ and $[1]$ too. This means that there cannot be two disjoint open sets that contain, respectively, $[0]$ and $[1]$, and so $\mathbb{R}/\sim$ is not Hausdorff.

Brilliant and clear, thank you very much Julio.
